# No such table - sqlite error

Tags: android, sqlite

Everytime I need to call my method RowID I'm getting an No Such Table error message. I would accept it, if the table didn't exist, but it does, so I don't get what's wrong with it.

Here is the error message:

```
05-06 13:51:23.429    4633-4633/pt.smartgeo.aees E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: pt.smartgeo.aees, PID: 4633
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: redes (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT  * FROM redes
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1314)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1253)
            at pt.smartgeo.aees.NetworksDBAdapter.RowID(NetworksDBAdapter.java:114)
            at pt.smartgeo.aees.CreateNetwork$1.onClick(CreateNetwork.java:57)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

wish is in this method:

```
public class NetworksDBAdapter {
private SQLiteDatabase database;
private NetworksDB networks;
private String[] allColumns = {NetworksDB.ID, NetworksDB.NETWORKD_ID, NetworksDB.NAME, NetworksDB.MACRO};

public NetworksDBAdapter(Context context) {
    networks = new NetworksDB(context);

    open();
}

public void open() throws SQLException {
    database = networks.getWritableDatabase();
}

public Network createNetwork(String id, String name, int macro) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(NetworksDB.NETWORKD_ID, id);
    values.put(NetworksDB.NAME, name);
    values.put(NetworksDB.MACRO, macro);
    long insertId = database.insert(NetworksDB.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    // To show how to query

    Cursor cursor = database.query(NetworksDB.TABLE_NAME, allColumns, PointsDB.ID + " = " +
            insertId, null,null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursorToPoint(cursor);
}

private Network cursorToPoint(Cursor cursor) {
    Network network = new
            Network(cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(3)));
    return network;
}

public void deleteNetwork(int idPoint){
    database.delete(NetworksDB.TABLE_NAME, PointsDB.ID + " = " + idPoint,
            null);
}

public void updateNetwork(int id, String idNetwork, String name, int macro){
    String where = "_id=?";
    String[] whereArgs = new String[] {String.valueOf(id)};
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(NetworksDB.NETWORKD_ID, idNetwork);
    values.put(NetworksDB.NAME, name);
    values.put(NetworksDB.MACRO, macro);
    database.update(PointsDB.TABLE_NAME, values, where, whereArgs);
}

public Cursor getNetworks(){
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT _id, NetworkID, name, macro from redes", null);
    return cursor;
}

public Network getNetwork(int id){
    Cursor cursor = database.query(PointsDB.TABLE_NAME, allColumns, NetworksDB.ID + " = " +
            id, null,null, null, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        return cursorToPoint(cursor);
    }
    return null;
}

public long count() {
    return DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(database,NetworksDB.TABLE_NAME);
}

public List<String> RowID(){
    List<String> List = new ArrayList<String>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + NetworksDB.TABLE_NAME;
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            List.add(cursor.getString(0));
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return List;
}
```

}

This is the line by the way:

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + NetworksDB.TABLE_NAME;
```

And this is my NetworksDB class

```
public class NetworksDB extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String ID = "_id";
    public static final String NETWORKD_ID = "NetworkID";
    public static final String NAME = "name";
    public static final String MACRO = "macro";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 3;

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "aees.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "redes";
    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "
            + TABLE_NAME + "( " + ID
            + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + NETWORKD_ID
            + " text not null, " + NAME + " text not null, "
            + MACRO + " text not null);";

    public NetworksDB(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w(PointsDB.class.getName(),
                "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                        + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data"
        );
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

Anyone has any ideia what's wrong with it? :/

Comment: How do you obtain the `database` in `RowID()`? Have you already uninstalled the app / cleared its data so that the database is recreated?

Comment: I will post the class where RowID is right away

Comment: @laalto just cleared all the data and it's now working. so the problem is solved, post solution so I can accept. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments clearing app data helped. Apparently your device already had a database file with the same name and version but without the table. Calling `getWritableDatabase()` just happily opened it but no lifecycle methods such as `onCreate()` or `onUpgrade()` were invoked.

Further reading: [When is SQLiteOpenHelper onCreate() / onUpgrade() run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21881992/when-is-sqliteopenhelper-oncreate-onupgrade-run)

Answer (score 2):

Your table is not being created, because of this line:

```
+ MACRO + " text not );";
```

It should be:

```
+ MACRO + " text not null);";
```

**[EDIT]**

This was true before you edited your question.

Comment: Doesn't explain the stacktrace though - for a syntax problem like this the exception would be different. Apparently the table creation code has not been run.

Comment: fixed it, it seems that was not the problem

Comment: Did you open your db first?

Comment: just post my DabataseAdapter class where I'm opening